# How to contain table within DIV

Tags: html, css, styles

I have an outer DIV tag that contains a table. The table contains 1 column or TD tag. This TD tag has a inner DIV that displays the company name.

Sometimes the company name is too long for the outer DIV depending on the width of the outer DIV. So I adding the following style to the TD's DIV tag:

```
style="width:95%; text-align: center; -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis; -o-text-overflow: ellipsis; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden"
```

This works fairly well, a long company name will be contained within the outer DIV with part of the company name missing and "..." at the end of the company name.

The problem I have is that if the outer DIV is sized to small or the company name is too long, then the company name TD tag will spill over into the unrelated DIV tag on the right.

This happens when the outer DIV is sized to approximately 400px but the company name is 700px. But a 600px company name works as expected inside the 400px outer DIV.

How can I get the table's TD and inner DIV tag always to display inside of the outer DIV tag's width?

Here is an example of what is happening. The first row is what I would like, but if the containing DIV width is narrower, then the ellipsis does not show and the table bleeds over to the DIV to the right: [jsfiddle exampl](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrytovar/jmspcatj/2/)

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have a bunch of `<div>`s with single cell tables in them, instead of something like one large table?

Comment: This is just an example that illustrates my larger problem. I wanted to break it down to simplify things.

Comment: Looks like the solution is to add overflow:hidden; on the container DIV. this will truncate the table and make it fit right.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the text inside the divs, use this class:

```
/* Source: http://snipplr.com/view/10979/css-cross-browser-word-wrap */
.wordwrap { 
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```